# Android : How to add animation while setting layout in same activity

Tags: android, animation, android-activity

I have multiple layout in an activity and i want to add some animation while changing the layout.

as we use overridePendingTransition() to add animation between activities. Can someone suggest how to apply animation without changing activities.

Thanks,
AK

Answer (score 0):

You can try [ViewFlipper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html), really handy class for animating between different layouts.

Check out [this](http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/06/android-viewflipper-example.html) or [this](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2013/11/example-of-viewflipper.html) examples